# Puppeteer: waitForSelector followed by click is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a dynamic site using puppeteer in node, but not able to click the required elements no matter what. Please help!

```
// this script parses the data from https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(90000);
  const url = "https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0});
  // await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
  await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District');
  await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District');
})();
```

Tried this too, but no luck:

```
  const selectButt = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District')
  );
  await selectButt.click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `<select>`, you probably don't want to click on it, but choose an option instead:

```js
await page.select('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District', '020'); // ALIPURDUAR
```

[Docs for `page.select`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.0.0&show=api-pageselectselector-values)

> Triggers a `change` and `input` event once all the provided options have been selected.

Comment: I tried it, did not work. lemme increase timeout

Comment: Why is `await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_2');` not working. I checked there is no special function for selecting radio button.

Comment: `  await page.evaluate(() => {
    var test = document.querySelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_2')
    test.click();
  })` worked for the radio button

Comment: I'm guessing it's because Puppeteer can't access it because of the CSS (it's positioned absolutely with a z-index of -1). But clicking on the label seems to work: `await page.click('[for=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_2]');`

Comment: Can i request you to help with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562491/puppeteer-page-evaluate-not-working-after-waitfornavigation-debug-not-working